# Azure Active Directory B2B cost when user is not assigned a license

Tags: azure-active-directory

I noticed when I went to the Azure portal under Active Directory, I could assign a user the license to Azure AD Premium P2 (I have a trial).

However, I also noticed that I don't need to assign a user this license (in the step above), and the user is able to reset their password.

I know that users can only reset their password if we are not using the free version of Azure AD.

Does this mean that the user above who is able to access the password reset page is counted part of the cost ($11.52 per month per user in this case), even though they haven't been assigned an explicit license in their profile?

Comment: Please take a look and let me know if you have any more query. Thanks and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are wanted to know whether the cost calculated if the user assigned to the specific licence.

For your understanding, in each subscriptions how many users has this `role access` would not be counted as cost , let's say, you have 10 users with this access but 2/3 user used it. So bill will be calculated for 2/3 uses not 10 users even you assigned 10 users for this.

Cost usually be calculated upon total uses. So don't worry about the cost on azure cloud. It has uses friendly metrics.

Usually prices Default usage quota is 50,000 objects. If you exceeded the this limit then the new metrics would be applied as per your uses.

> **Note:** For more details you could check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/enterprise/billing-enterprise-api-pricesheet). Check your bills [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/enterprise/billing-enterprise-api-usage-detail)

Comment: If i 10 users, and no one is assigned with the Premium P2 license, does that mean there will be no charge? Or, is there a charge for using password reset in this case? Of course, this is a simple case example.

Comment: Definitely there be a minimum charged for. For pay as you go mode there will be no charges. Even if you assign 10 but not use any features. But with this mode many features does not support.